# MongoDB: Aggregate with distinct

Tags: mongodb

I checked the various Stackoverflow threads and couldn't find the answer.

I have a collection with various score entries, each containing some data about the user on the day he played.

Here's a simplified example of 4 documents:

```
{
    user_id:        1,
    someint:        10,
    agerange:       "25-35",
    score:          12345
},
{
    user_id:        2,
    someint:        10,
    agerange:       "35-45",
    someotherkey:   12345
},
{
    user_id:        1,
    someint:        8,
    agerange:       "25-35",
    score:          12345
},
{
    user_id:        3,
    someint:        10,
    agerange:       "13-18",
    someotherkey:   12345
}
```

In this example, user #1 played twice.

I want to obtain stats on the age-range of the players, without counting the same user twice.

Here's an example of what I'm expecting:

```
{
    _id: "25-35",  // <- User #1 counted only once
    total: 1
},
{
    _id: "35-45",
    total: 1
},
{
    _id: "13-18",
    total: 1
}
```

Using the aggregation rule I have so far, users get counted as many time as they have played:

```
[{
    $project: {
        text:   "$agerange"
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id:    '$text',
        total:  {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}]
```

When I group by UID, I get each user's UI in the output, which is not what I expect.

Can't seem to find a valid structure for a double-grouping.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with double group :

```
db.players.aggregate([    
{
    $group: {
        _id: {user_id: '$user_id', agerange: '$agerange'}
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: '$_id.agerange',
        total : {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}
])
```

**First group**

The first `$group` is use to make a distinct on `$user_id` and `$agerange`.If i execute the first group only with a `$sum` :

*Data:*

```
db.players.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("529e566bfdfd61191c830099"), "user_id" : 1, "someint" : 10, "agerange" : "25-35", "score" : 12345 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("529e5680fdfd61191c83009a"), "user_id" : 2, "someint" : 10, "agerange" : "35-45", "someotherkey" : 12345 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("529e568ffdfd61191c83009b"), "user_id" : 1, "someint" : 8, "agerange" : "25-35", "score" : 12345 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("529e569dfdfd61191c83009c"), "user_id" : 3, "someint" : 10, "agerange" : "13-18", "someotherkey" : 12345 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("529e5c4cf829b266f4c3e813"), "user_id" : 2, "someint" : 8, "agerange" : "25-35", "score" : 12345 }
```

*Group result :*

```
db.players.aggregate([  { $group: { _id: {user_id: '$user_id', agerange: '$agerange'}, total : { $sum: 1 } } }]);
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "user_id" : 2,
                "agerange" : "25-35"
            },
            "total" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "user_id" : 3,
                "agerange" : "13-18"
            },
            "total" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "user_id" : 2,
                "agerange" : "35-45"
            },
            "total" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "user_id" : 1,
                "agerange" : "25-35"
            },
            "total" : 2
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I have one object per couple `$user_id` / `$agerange`

`$sum` is useless in our case so i removed it

**Second group**

The second group is applied on the first group result. I need to count how many times  the `$agerange` value is returned, so i make a group on the `$_id.agerange` of the first group's result

I hope it's clear for you my english is very bad :)

Comment: Working perfectly! Also helps me to understand the structure for this kind of query. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I understood the way it worked, but your additional explanation will probably help people who were also searching for the answer. The query is already in production on our stats interface.